# javascript filename enclosed between two curly braces

Tags: javascript, curl

I have encountered a statement where javascript filename is enclosed in double curly braces...
{{javascript.core.js}}

what does enclosing a filename in double curly braces actually do ?Please need an answe

addin the link ->https://lava.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Lava/Lava.Web/lava/scripts/dev/lava.js

Comment: you'll have to give context -- it may be from a templating engine and loading that file.

Comment: See https://github.com/janl/mustache.js for an example of a templating engine that uses this syntax.

Answer (score 2):

That is not Javascript. If it was, it would be a code block inside a code block that accessed the `js` property in an object in the `core` property in an object in the variable `javascript`, and discards the result.

This is likely a tag for a server side processing engine, judging by the identifiers it's something Javascript based like Node.js.